# ciclo for para cálculo de uma função

Tags: r

Pretendo efectuar um ciclo `for` mas não está a resultar. Os meus conhecimentos de 'R' ainda são parcos. Pretendo calcular uma função `F(y, x) = 1 + y + y^2 + ... + y^x = sum(y^(0:x))`.

Escrevi o seguinte código, mas está a dar um resultado que não é o que pretendo. Qual o erro?

```
> sum <- 1 
> for(i in 0:3){
+     for(y in 0:3){
+             sum <- sum + y ^ (i)
+     }
+ }
```

> print( sum )
>   [1] 61

Comment: 0) Escolha outro nome para a variável `sum`, já é uma função do R; 1) Comece com `sum <- 0`; 2) Tire o ciclo de dentro, não está lá a fazer nada.

Comment: Nota ao comentário de cima: Se quiser pode começar com `sum <- 1` mas então o ciclo `for` será para valores `1:x` e não `0:x`.

Answer (score 2):

Seu código está fazendo exatamente o que especificou. Você forneceu um valor de x e um valor de y, e foi esse o resultado retornado:

```
> 0^0+0
[1] 1
```

Para usar `for`, você deve especificar uma sequência, por exemplo:

```
x <- 3

> for(i in x) print(i+1)
[1] 4

> for(i in 1:x) print(i+1)
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
```

Para armazenar os valores, deve ter um objeto de dimensão apropriada para receber o resultado de cada volta, ou terá apenas o último valor:

```
for(i in 0:x) y = x ^ i + x
> y 
[1] 30
# o objeto y teve o valor atualizado a cada volta

y <- rep(NA, x+1)
for(i in 0:x) y[i+1] = x ^ i + x
> y
[1]  4  6 12 30
```

Mas R é otimizado para operações vetoriais, é melhor evitar loops sempre que possível. Você já chegou na solução quando editou sua questão, apenas não percebeu que era apenas isso:

```
suaFuncao <- function(y, x) sum(y^(0:x))

> suaFuncao(2, 3)
[1] 15
```

Comment: Efetivamente a sua solução que evita os loops é a melhor solução. No entanto para este caso em concreto tenho de usar o ciclo 'for'. Quanto ao ciclo 'for' fiz o seguinte mas obtenho um erro. '> n <- 0:4
> y <- 0:4
> for(i in 0:x) y = 1 + y ^2 + y ^ x
Warning message:
In 0:n : numerical expression has 5 elements: only the first used'

Comment: Basicamente pretendia exatamente aquilo que tem na 'suaFuncao' em que o utilizador coloca o valor de X e o valor de Y e retorna o valor da função mas com ciclo 'for'

Comment: Você já chegou no código, é só que não percebeu que é śo não usar um loop. Editei a resposta indicando isso.

Comment: A sua função @Carlos é uma solução simples e clara para mim, fiquei a perceber mais um pouco da matéria. Mas para o caso em concreto o formador pediu um ´ciclo for´. Editei o meu tópico com algo mais que fiz, mas o resultado não está correto. Neste caso o resultado deveria ser ´40´ e não ´61´ . Dá para ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Aqui está um ciclo `for` bem simples. E a comparação com o resultado da função da [resposta do Carlos Eduardo Lagosta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/339463/ciclo-for-para-c%c3%a1lculo-de-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o/339482#339482).

```
suaFuncao <- function(y, x) sum(y^(0:x))

suaFuncao2 <- function(y, x){
  s <- 1
  for(k in seq_len(x)) s <- s + y^k
  s
}

suaFuncao(2, 3)
#[1] 15

suaFuncao2(2, 3)
#[1] 15
```